# A group with finitely many subgroups must be a finite group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that a group that has only a finite number of subgroups must be a finite group.(Fraleigh, A First Course in abstract Algebra-7th Edition,pg.67) I could not show properly so I need help. Thank you.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: consider all subgroups $\langle g \rangle$ generated by an element $g \in G$.

Answer (score 1):

Every element $g\in G$ generates a subgroup $\{\ldots,g^{-1},g^0,g^1,g^2,\ldots\}$. Each of these subgroups has to be finite, else it would be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, which has infinitely many subgroups. What can you conclude?

Comment: By that you only showed that every element in $G$ must have finite order. But there are infinite groups such that  every element has finite order as $G=Z_2\times Z_2 \times ...$

Comment: @mesel Read the question. There's only finitely many subgroups.

Comment: But you only showed that order of every element is finite, my example just shows that there are infinite groups with finite order for every element.

Comment: what I mean your argument is not enough to coclude the result, if you do not think something further.

Comment: @mesel Notice that I didn't use the word "order" even once in my answer. Because I don't need to. A group is obviously a union of the subgroups generated by its elements. There's only finitely many different subgroups and each of them is finite. Are you saying that a finite sum of finite numbers can be infinite??

Comment: Now, it is okey. I did not get the point how to conclude. thank you and you should be more gentle when somebody ask about a point in your answer.